# example usage of clojure.set index function

Tags: clojure

I looked at [docs](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.set-api.html) but its description does not give any hint/example about usage for index function except the following description.

```
Usage: (index xrel ks)


Returns a map of the distinct values of ks in the xrel mapped to a
set of the maps in xrel with the corresponding values of ks.
```

Please share some code examples for `index` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several [examples available](http://conj.io/store/org.clojure/clojure/1.6.0/clojure.set/index/) on [Grimoire](http://conj.io/). Grimoire often has more extensive examples than the official Clojure docs.

> ```
> (use '[clojure.set :only (index)])
>
> ;; Suppose you have a set of descriptions of the weights of animals:
>
> user=> (def weights #{ {:name 'betsy :weight 1000}
>                        {:name 'jake :weight 756}
>                        {:name 'shyq :weight 1000} })
>
>
> ;; You want the names of all the animals that weight 1000. One way to do
> ;; that uses `index`. First, you can group the set elements (the maps)
> ;; so that those with the same weights are in the same group.
>
> user=> (def by-weight (index weights [:weight]))
> #'user/by-weight
>
> ;; index returns a map.  The keys are maps themselves, where {:weight
> ;; 756} and {:weight 1000} are taken from the maps in the weights set.  The
> ;; values in the map returned by index are sets that contain map entries
> ;; from the above weights set.
>
> user=> by-weight
> {{:weight 756} #{{:name jake, :weight 756}}, 
>  {:weight 1000} #{{:name shyq, :weight 1000} 
>                   {:name betsy, :weight 1000}}}
> ```